# How can I split a same file view in Xcode editor?

Tags: xcode, text-editor

I know I can use **View > Assistant Editor** to split **two** different file in the same view. However, I do not know to split a **same** file like this. As an example, when I am editing the tail of the file, and I would meanwhile edit the "@implementation" at the beginning of the file, how should I do? I don't want to jump in the file all the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View the .m file or the .h file in the normal editor. Open the assistant editor. The counterpart will appear in the other pane. If you use a trackpad, do a three-finger up or down swipe to switch counterparts. If you do this in the pane with the .h it will switch to the .m or visa-versa. Or use the Ctrl-Cmd-Up arrow (or down arrow) to switch counterparts. You will now have the same .h or .m in both panes.

Comment: So simple, yet so brilliant. +1 for all the minutes you will save me.

Comment: Thanks! And I have found the original document from Apple: ["Split the Editor Area to Display Related Content"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/040-Edit_Source_Code/edit_source_code.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH8-SW42)